# How to plot a 3D triangle mesh shape with a specific colormap in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, mesh, point-clouds

A 3D triangle mesh shape is represented by vertices and triangle faces.
For example, `shape` in matlab which has `shape.X, shape.Y, shape.Z(the vertices) and shape.TRIV(the triangle faces)` can be seen as a 3D triangle mesh shape.

My question is **how to visualize such a shape in MATLAB with a specific colormap**.

(for example, the **colormap** can be defined as a **distance vector** of `length(shape.X)` whose elements are **Euclidean distances of all vertices to a single vertex `M`**, in this situation, **the cooler colors related to the smaller distances, and the hotter colors related to the larger distances**.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on @Suever's answer, I add some extra code to make the shape plot smoother and add a camera light. By the way, if the shape is a point cloud without faces, it's better to choose `scatter3` instead of `plot3`.

```
vertices = cat(2, shape.X(:), shape.Y(:), shape.Z(:));

%// Compute distance of each vertex from the origin
distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, vertices, [0 0 0]).^2, 2)); 

%// Create the patch object
h = patch('Vertices', vertices, 'Faces', shape.TRIV);

%// Set the vertex colors and use interpolation to shade the faces
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'FaceVertexCData', distances,'EdgeColor', 'none');
%or use shading interp instead of setting 'EdgeColor'=='none' to make the shape smooth;

%// Scale the color limits to your data
set(gca, 'clim', [min(distances(:)), max(distances(:))])

% add a colorbar
colorbar

% change the colormap
colormap(jet(64))

%use the same unit length along each axis  and fit the axes box tightly around the data.
axis image 

% turn off the coordinate
axis off

% set the camlight strength, trial and error
set(h, 'AmbientStrength',0.25, 'SpecularStrength',0.0,'DiffuseStrength',0.5);
lighting phong;
camlight left; %left,right,head
set(gcf,'Renderer','opengl');  %‘opengl’,'zbuffer'
```

If it's a point cloud：

```
h2=scatter3(X,Y,Z,'.');
view([0,90]);
h2.CData=distances;
axis image;
set(gca, 'clim', [min(distances(:)), max(distances(:))]);
colormap(jet(64));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) object to show your 3D shape and then use the `FaceVertexCData` and `FaceColor` properties of the resulting patch to set a value which can automatically be mapped to the axes color limits.

```
vertices = cat(2, shape.X(:), shape.Y(:), shape.Z(:));

%// Create the patch object
h = patch('Vertices', vertices, ...
          'Faces', shape.TRIV);

%// Compute distance of each vertex from the origin
distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, vertices, [0 0 0]).^2, 2));

%// Set the vertex colors and use interpolation to shade the faces
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
       'FaceVertexCData', distances);

%// Scale the color limits to your data
set(gca, 'clim', [min(distances(:)), max(distances(:))])
```

Comment: What if the shape is a point cloud without faces(shape.TRIV)?

Comment: @GuWang If you have a point cloud, then you'll need to use `plot3` or `scatter3`

Comment: How can I make the shape plotted by patch smoother? And how to add a light source to the shape?

Comment: @GuWang you can turn on FaceLighting and then create a `light`

Comment: Could you give me some example code for using FaceLighting?